# Android- How to display items with variable space between then

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a horizontal layout to display 5 icons.

I would like to know if there is a way to display the first one always X dp from margin left and the last one X dp from the margin right and the others with the same space between then.

With `LinearLayout` the space is always the same even when I change the device , so sometimes my horizontal row became much more bigger than the space that the icons use and with `RelativeLayout` i just can align 3 items in this way ( `alignParentLeft`, `centerInParent`, `alignParentRight`)

Answer (score 0):

With `RelativeLayout` I think you can easily put three of your icons at the proper place. For the last two icons, I don't think there's something you can do in your xml. Actually I have met the same problem before.

An approach is (maybe not the best one) to calculate the margins of the two icons in your java code. It's really easy to get the parent view width (in pixels) and you know how much space(a percentage) there should be before/after your views. Just a multiplication and `addView` with `LayoutParam` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

A `LinearLayout` with `android:width="match_parent"`, `android:layout_marginRight` and `android:layout_marginLeft` within a `RelativeLayout` should work.

The Linear Layout will be xdp from the left and xdp from the right, with the icons spaced evenly inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Linear Layout, you can use the weight attribute to calculate the correct spacing between the images.

Set each of their weights to 1 so that they take an equal space in the row :

```
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

I hope that can assist you.